# Using LessCSS outside RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, less

I'm working with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to organize my [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) apps, and I'm trying using [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) during the site develop outside `require` to avoid the page renders the styles very slow.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/js/config.js" src="/js/libs/require/require-2.1.8.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="http://website.local/css/styles.less">
<script type="text/javascript">
    less = {
        env:"develop"
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/less/less-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

When I load `LessCSS` JavaScript file outside `RequireJS` to compile my LESS code I get this error on `Chrome debugger`:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return r}
```

The error is thrown only if I load the external library outside `RequireJS` requests.

Does exist some way to avoid RequireJS throws this error and let me work with an external JavaScript library like LessCSS?

Comment: what do you mean by 'outside requirejs'? How are you doing the loading?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear

Answer (score 2):

Try loading (and executing) less *before* require; i.e.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="http://website.local/css/styles.less">
<script type="text/javascript">
    less = {
        env:"develop"
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/less/less-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/js/config.js" src="/js/libs/require/require-2.1.8.min.js"></script>
```

This way less will not see the AMD environment and load as standard script.

Otherwise you should load less by `require()`-ing it (e.g. the rwquire-less plugin that mallim mentions).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using guybedford's require-less plugin (https://github.com/guybedford/require-less) to help you.

Another alternative is to use a less compiler to oompiled to css and load the css instead.